# How to implement Spring Boot - Angular app - End to End encryption

Tags: angular, spring-boot, encryption

I have spring backend and Angular frontend. I would like to implement end to end encrytion of the payload.

Are there something like interceptors to do this.

I would like to know, how to do it. Please advice

Comment: Use https for internet.

Comment: If we use https protocol that's it? Is there no way people can open developer console and see clear text in browser?

Answer (score 1):

Answering here due to limited space available in comments. The question is why do you want encryption :

1. If you want that any message between the 'browser on your client device' and your server, to be secured - Use HTTPS. That is it.
2. It seems you want that server's API response not to be visible as plain text in the browser's console. A smart hacker can always decrypt this information as decryption key is also present on the client app. (Not the browser). You can use crypto js for such cases, but this is for name sake only.